# Where to put test pages and components in a Vue / Nuxt app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a big Nuxt app. We frequently create test pages or components to test out concepts and code. Sometimes we create prototype pages, like TestPageWithScrollableContent.vue

I don't want to delete these pages when we're done with them, but I don't want to distribute them in the production app either.

Is there a place to put them in the Nuxt directory structure where we can call them at development time, but not have them compiled into a production build?

In Java, this is easy. There is a separate source tree for test code. I'm looking for the equivalent in Vue / Nuxt.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore specific files and directories in the build process using `.nuxtignore`

For example:

```
# ignore layout foo.vue
layouts/foo.vue
# ignore layout files whose name ends with -ignore.vue
layouts/*-ignore.vue

# ignore page bar.vue
pages/bar.vue
# ignore page inside ignore folder
pages/ignore/*.vue

# ignore store baz.js
store/baz.js
# ignore store files match *.test.*
store/ignore/*.test.*

# ignore middleware files under foo folder except foo/bar.js
middleware/foo/*.js
!middleware/foo/bar.js
```

More info here:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-ignore/

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, .nuxtignore makes Nuxt ignore things at development time as well as built time. It means that I can't test any of the test components or pages.

Comment: Ah. In that case, use a logical operator and the ignore property in nuxt.config.js. Eg. ignore: [process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'glob/for/your/files']. If environment is prod, files in the glob are ignored.